# Assign new values to table without considering where its inserted in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have table
students_to_assign

| Students |
| --- |
| 12 |
| 15 |
| 18 |

and table for chairs_arrangement

| Chair | Assigned_Student |
| --- | --- |
| 5a | 12 |
| 6b | 24 |
| 10z | null |
| 10v | null |

I want to assign chairs to the students:

- Chair can be assigned only if Assigned_Student is null.
- If the student was already assigned a chair he will not assign it to a new chair.
- If there are more students than chairs we will assign chairs until the table is full
- the student list is the size of 1 million records

can you help with a query that can run in parallel with other queries or to do it in 1 batch

I was trying to create students_to_assign with column chairs and when creating add to the table students_to_assign but that says that I need to lock the table and the process takes a very long time and resources (about 30 sec).

I would like, if possible, a solution that inserts directly into chairs_arrangement with no consideration what chair is assigned as long as it answer the rules i said above (not assigned before, no duplicate students)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Why is this tagged with MySQL if you need a solution working in PostgreSQL?

Comment: I removed the SQL tag, originally added as I think there might be a global solution that is workable both for Postgres and SQL.
as for my code as I said it is was taking way too long, and also do some more things that seems irrelevant to the core question

Comment: Please share more details, like the table structure, the query you are using, and the execution plan for that query